# Rendering LaTex code inside html tags in a jupyter notebook running inside VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, latex

How can I correctly display the following html table correctly in a jupyter notebook running in VsCode? The table is rendered correctly on the browser but not inside VsCode.

The LaTex wrapper $$ works for elements outside the html table but not for the elements inside. Is there a way to resolve this?

Edit: I read somewhere that jupyter uses MathJax to achieve this, can it be used inside VsCode as well?

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>  </td> 
        <td> **Shape of W** </td> 
        <td> **Shape of b**  </td> 
        <td> **Activation** </td>
        <td> **Shape of Activation** </td> 
    <tr>

    <tr>
        <td> **Layer 1** </td> 
        <td> $(n^{[1]},12288)$ </td> 
        <td> $(n^{[1]},1)$ </td> 
        <td> $Z^{[1]} = W^{[1]}  X + b^{[1]} $ </td> 

        <td> $(n^{[1]},209)$ </td> 
    <tr>

    <tr>
        <td> **Layer 2** </td> 
        <td> $(n^{[2]}, n^{[1]})$  </td> 
        <td> $(n^{[2]},1)$ </td> 
        <td>$Z^{[2]} = W^{[2]} A^{[1]} + b^{[2]}$ </td> 
        <td> $(n^{[2]}, 209)$ </td> 
    <tr>

       <tr>
        <td> $\vdots$ </td> 
        <td> $\vdots$  </td> 
        <td> $\vdots$  </td> 
        <td> $\vdots$</td> 
        <td> $\vdots$  </td> 
    <tr>

   <tr>
        <td> **Layer L-1** </td> 
        <td> $(n^{[L-1]}, n^{[L-2]})$ </td> 
        <td> $(n^{[L-1]}, 1)$  </td> 
        <td>$Z^{[L-1]} =  W^{[L-1]} A^{[L-2]} + b^{[L-1]}$ </td> 
        <td> $(n^{[L-1]}, 209)$ </td> 
    <tr>


   <tr>
        <td> **Layer L** </td> 
        <td> $(n^{[L]}, n^{[L-1]})$ </td> 
        <td> $(n^{[L]}, 1)$ </td>
        <td> $Z^{[L]} =  W^{[L]} A^{[L-1]} + b^{[L]}$</td>
        <td> $(n^{[L]}, 209)$  </td> 
    <tr>

</table>

Remember that when we compute $W X + b$ in python, it carries out broadcasting. For example, if: 

$$ W = \begin{bmatrix}
    j  & k  & l\\
    m  & n & o \\
    p  & q & r 
\end{bmatrix}\;\;\; X = \begin{bmatrix}
    a  & b  & c\\
    d  & e & f \\
    g  & h & i 
\end{bmatrix} \;\;\; b =\begin{bmatrix}
    s  \\
    t  \\
    u
\end{bmatrix}\tag{2}$$

Then $WX + b$ will be:

$$ WX + b = \begin{bmatrix}
    (ja + kd + lg) + s  & (jb + ke + lh) + s  & (jc + kf + li)+ s\\
    (ma + nd + og) + t & (mb + ne + oh) + t & (mc + nf + oi) + t\\
    (pa + qd + rg) + u & (pb + qe + rh) + u & (pc + qf + ri)+ u
\end{bmatrix}\tag{3}  $$
```